# flutter : how to persist a List<num> using shared preferences?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

how to persist a List like `List<num> = [2.5, 5, 7.5, 10]` using `SharedPreferences` please ?

EDIT : how to convert stored data as `String` or `List<String>` to List ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to convert your list of integers to a List of Strings,
then you save it in shared preferences.

You do the opposite when loading.

This is a complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _save,
          child: new Text('Save my list of int'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_save() async {

  List<int> myListOfIntegers = [1,2,3,4];
  List<String> myListOfStrings=  myListOfIntegers.map((i)=>i.toString()).toList();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>()) ;
  List<int> myOriginaList = myList.map((i)=> int.parse(i)).toList();
  print('Your list  $myOriginaList');
  await prefs.setStringList('mylist', myListOfStrings);
}
```

Don't forget to add this to your pup spec.yaml file:

```
shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
```

Comment: worked perfectly, just used `List<num>` and `num.parse()` instead , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, there is no way to store list of numbers. But you implement it using:

```
 setStringList(String key, List<String> value) → Future<bool>
```

Saves a list of strings value to persistent storage in the background.

Implementation:

```
Future<bool> setStringList(String key, List<String> value) =>
    _setValue('StringList', key, value);
```

Another alternate way is like store whole list as a String.

Full documentation can be found in the [Flutter packages repository](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences).

Hope this will help you