# Flutter how to add more string in setStringList instead of replacing old data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In `sharedprocedures` we have setStringList which I am using . Issue is that I want to add more strings dynamically in that list. But I can't find any proper way to do that.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return await prefs.setStringList("favourites", id);
```

Like here is my code as I want to save favourite Ids in that list, instead of replacing it

Is there any solution of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter : how to persist a List<num> using shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456163/flutter-how-to-persist-a-listnum-using-shared-preferences)

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55637008/6883282

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

```
var currentList = prefs.getStringList("favourites") ?? [];
currentList.add("id");
await prefs.setStringList("favourites", currentList);
```